# How to clear file's content without close it?

Tags: visual-c++

I need open a file with `OF_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE` to prevent other threads or process read old dirty data. So I need clear the content after I open it and before I close it. The code might like this:

```
HFILE file = OpenFile(path, buff, OF_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE);
ReadFile(file, ...);  // read all content of file
ClearFileContent(file);  // here I need such a function to clear content of file
CloseHandle(file);  // close file handle
```

I have read the [File Management Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364232(v=vs.85).aspx) but didn't found what I want, so which API should I use to clear file's content before I close it?

Comment: SetFilePointer() to seek to the start of the file, SetEndOfFile() to truncate it.  Do you *really* want to leave empty files lying around?  Deleting the file is usually the better way to signal "there is no data".  Something you have to deal with anyway.

Comment: @HansPassant Can I delete a file when the file is being opened ? I just want only one thread or process can read the data and others read nothing.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh, I see. I can lock one empty file and operate on another file.

Comment: You can delete the file while it is open by calling `SetFileInformationByHandle` with `FileDispositionInfo`.  The file will then be deleted when all handles to it are closed.  If you have the only handle, then it will be deleted when you call `CloseHandle`.